# How to view form from source code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I have just started working on Java Swing project. As an IDE I am using IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains.

In the project I can see the `.java` files related to GUI.

Do you know how I can view these files in GUI Designer? Or Generate output of  these files in GUI Designer in IntelliJ IDEA or any other IDE.

I googled it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Depends on the kind of forms, e.g. you can't show forms created in NetBeans.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-opening-forms.html), Creating Snapshots section.

Comment: Thanks Cray Coder for the reply. I tired that and it failed with error "Failed to create snapshot: Read timed out". Do you have any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have A swing project with a GUI in it then you should see .form files next to the class it is bound to like this: [Class bound to a swing form file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfMI1.png)

Double clicking this .form should open the GUI designer. If you want to create a class with a GUI tied to it then use: Right click > New > GUI Form

Comment: Thanks for you reply. My problem is that I got .java files but not .form files and I don't how to generate .form file from .java files.

Comment: @ajay Can you edit your post and include one of the Java files related to the gui?

Answer (score 0):

In two ways, you can see the file in GUI Designer:

Double click to .form file in Project view.

In .java file you can see which code part bounds in which GUI component at the left side of the editor as an icon. So just click the related icon to view related component.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. My problem is that I got .java files but not .form files and I don't how to generate .form file from .java files.